# Can I make YouTube videos where I read parts of a book aloud

Tags: intellectual-property, public-domain, youtube, authorship

I'm learning languages and in my opinion, one way to improve my skills is to read books aloud. Making it a habit would help me with my vocabulary, pronunciation, grammar, etc.

I also think there might be some people online who would be interested in listening to books that I read aloud.

Therefore, I wonder, can I read parts of a book aloud online? Could I publish these videos on YouTube? Is that legal? I don't mind reading from older books, as I read those books might be public domain

Comment: Vince, for help with your vocabulary and grammar, you may find the English Language Learner Stack Exchange helpful (ell.stackexchange.com), as well as possibly the English Stack Exchange (english.stackexchange.com); though for learning English, I would recommend the former.

Comment: Go to librivox.org where your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on where you are

Answer (score 3):

**The following answer is based on US-law. I am not a lawyer; this is not legal advice.**

If the book you read is in the public domain* you should be fine. Otherwise what you are doing is copyright infringement and probably not protected by fair use**.

One of the rights granted to copyright holders is to control derivative works, and transference to different mediums, which is what your recordings would be.

**Under US law**, whether an instance of copyright infringement is fair use is evaluated on a case-by-case basis, weighing four points:

1. the purpose and character of one's use
2. the nature of the copyrighted work
3. what amount and proportion of the whole work was taken
4. the effect of the use upon the potential market for, or value of the copyrighted work

In my non-lawyer evaluation, point 1 depends on what you do in your video (unless you monetize your Youtube video, in which case it is likely to be decided against you), but if you are merely reading the book out aloud, it is unlikely to be in your favor (although it may not be against you as an "educational tool").

Point 2 depends on what is being read, with a informative work (e.g. a textbook) being more likely to be fair use than a creative work (e.g. a novel).

Point 3 depends on how much and what proportion of a work you use; since you are presumably reading a whole book, this would most likely be ruled against you.

Point 4 would almost certainly be decided against you, as you are essentially creating an unauthorized audiobook.

**In summary**, you can read a book aloud. You can record your reading of it for your personal use. You should NOT upload it to Youtube, or other sharing sites.

*Note that different countries have differing rules on when a book enters the public domain, and since the internet crosses borders, multiple rule sets may apply.

Comment: "You can record your reading of it for your personal use." On what legal basis is this allowed, even if the other three factors (1-3) are against your use? Presumably recording it for personal use has no impact on the market, so factor 4 seems to be in your favour.

Comment: @Brandin: Copyright is decided on a case by case basis, as is what weight should be given; It is possible that a single factor can outweigh the other three. Also, Factor 1 would also be in the OP's favor if it the purpose and character of their use was "personal", but the OP mentions sharing it on youtube, which would not be personal use.

Comment: Recording the reading for your own purposes is infringement, since you're making another copy.  It's very likely that the copyright owner won't find about it, very likely that the owner won't care about it, and it's exceedingly unlikely that the owner will pursue the case legally, but it's still unlawful.

Comment: Your "technically" is technically wrong; the law is worded such that it's not an infringement.  "Notwithstanding the provisions of sections 106 and 106A, the fair use of a copyrighted work... is not an infringement of copyright." - 17 USC 107.

Comment: Factor 1 is not automatically tilted against fair use by charging for access, let alone b y "monetizing" which essentially means carrying advertisements. The question spoke of reading "parts of books" so factor 3 is =very much in play. And something held to be fair use is not an infringement, not even technically.

Comment: In Hungary, you have a right to create copies for your own purpose; this would likely apply here, too.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: While I agree Factor 1 is not automatically tilted, from what I have seen and read, it seems to lean that way, especially without any thing "counter leaning"; If you have any sources describing the opposite, I'd love to see them (genuinely). You are potentially right about point #3; I made an presumption, from "there might be some people online who would be interested in listening to books that I read aloud" that the book would be read in its entirety (though not necessarily all in one video).

Comment: @kisspuska: There is something similar in US law, referred to as "personal use", referred to in the second bolded section "In summary"; however, since this question talks about sharing said video on Youtube, my understanding is that use is no longer "personal".

Comment: @DM Thank you for those sources; my understanding was incorrect. I thought fair use was an affirmative defense, rather than an exclusion from infringement.

Comment: @sharur On further research, it seems that the courts *treat* it like an affirmative defense, though, even though it shouldn't be according to the language in the statute. https://www.law.uw.edu/wlr/print-edition/print-edition/vol-90/2/fair-use-an-affirmative-defense

Comment: @DM: Well that certainly explains my confusion, then!

Answer (score 1):

If the work is in the public domain (probably through the copyright having expired) there is no copyright protection, so the issue of fair use does not arise.

Fair Use is an ***exception to copyright*** in US law. In the copyright laws of other countries than the US there are various exceptions provided, but they not are very close to fair use in scope. Copyright infringement suits can be brought in any country where infringement takes place. The local copyright law applies in such cases.

There are not enough specific facts provided to make a reliable fair use analysis, much less consider any of the various non-US exceptions to copyright.

If the apparent purpose is educational, that tends to tilt toward fair use for factor 1. Just how much of the book would be read aloud would need to be known to make even an approximate judgement on factor 3, and that might also affect factor 4, particularly on whether the video could serve as a replacement for the original.

In some counties there are specific exceptions to copyright for "personal use" but not in US law to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Educational purpose would also be very probative. Short excerpts to help others learn pronunciation and intonation and accent, particular from words most often read in a particular source (e.g. "muggle") would fair much better in fair use analysis.