# Is it legal to teach a book in you tube

Tags: copyright, israel

I want to teach a subject using a book.

On the book there are copyrights

I dont get any payment for my videos, its free, i just want to teach the subject from a book i learn and publish the lessons in youtube for all.

Again, there is no money i will get from the videos.

Am i doing an ilegal thing? or its ok?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make YouTube videos where I read parts of a book aloud](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31298/can-i-make-youtube-videos-where-i-read-parts-of-a-book-aloud)

Comment: No because im not reading parts of the book, im using the book, Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Copyright only protects expression, and does not give an author ownership over the subject matter. So you can teach "about" the book in any forum you want. The only limit pertains to actual copying, for example you can't convert the text of a book into some Powerpoint-like display and then run those slides as your video. You can do that for money, if you want.

Comment: thank you for the asnwer. 
I summaraize the material on paper from the book, of course some of that is expicit copy of what is wrriten - i cant change any word.

then in my video i am explaining the material (not just video it) and not reading it. 

Here is an example, if you understand hebrew. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqV2-ELlofA

Thanks again.